# How to find the element for below code in WebDriver?

Tags: selenium2, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium Webdriver in C#. I am trying to find the element for below given Angular code.

```
"<div class="ViewMenu" ng-class="{'selectedViewMenu':SearchObj.param.View=='Videos'}" style="">Videos</div>"
```

I tried it using `driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='ViewMenu selectedViewMenu']"));`

but it doesn't work.

Comment: what you have to do with this? Is it dropdown list/textbox/button? which environment you are using to run this script?

Selenium V-?
browser-?

paste error msg that your IDE shows.

Comment: I recommend removing `selectedViewMenu` from your selector.  It may not hurt but it definitely will not help.

Answer (score 3):

Check with different XPath-

XPath 1:

```
//div[@class='ViewMenu selectedViewMenu']
```

XPath 2:

```
//*[@class='ViewMenu selectedViewMenu']
```

OR Try with **CSS Selector**:

```
driver.FindElement(By.cssSelector(".ViewMenu.selectedViewMenu"));
```

Answer (score 1):

one choice by CLASS:

```
driver.findElement(By.className("element class"))
```

another choice: by css selector (you need to work on css selector)

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("css selector"))

driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("ng-class["\{\'selectedViewMenu\'\:SearchObj.param.View=='Videos'\}]")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this xpath: `//div[@class='ViewMenu' and text() = 'Videos']`
because class `selectedViewMenu` is probably only when element is selected.